# convert the result in the context manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

I have my own context manager class: `my_context_manager`, I want to convert the result to the giving `output_type`, can be for example `str`, `list`, `int` whatever, I tried to play with the `__enter__` , `__exit__` methods, in  `my_context_manager`, but I didn't find how to get the variable used inside the with scope,

```py
with my_context_manager(output_type): # output_type can be str, int etc
    result = 5 + 2 #( or any other any arithmetical operation operation)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't manipulate the code running in the `with` block with a context manager.

Basically all that `with` does is call `__enter__` and `__exit__` on the object you  `with`, so your code is (if we skip exception handling) equivalent to

```
_anonymous_var = my_context_manager(output_type)
_anonymous_var.__enter__()
result = 5 + 2
_anonymous_var.__exit__()
```

## EDIT

> if we replaced the 5 and the 2 with a custom object, can i modify the result object to converted based on the giving type in the context manager?

You could return the custom object from the context manager, like so:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def my_context_manager(output_type):
    def caster(in_value):
        out_value = output_type(in_value)
        print(f"cast {in_value!r} to {out_value!r}")
        return out_value

    yield caster


with my_context_manager(int) as c:
    result = c(5) + c("2")
    print(result)

with my_context_manager(str) as c:
    result = c(5) + c(2)
    print(result)
```

The output is

```
cast 5 to 5
cast '2' to 2
7
cast 5 to '5'
cast 2 to '2'
52
```

but if you don't want to return a brand new thing, you can also just modify an existing object within the `with`:

```
class MySpecialClass:
    behavior = ...

@contextmanager
def behave_differently(behavior):
    old_behavior = MySpecialClass.behavior
    try:
        MySpecialClass.behavior = behavior
        yield
    finally:
        MySpecialClass.behavior = old_behavior
```

### EDIT 2

Using a similar `MyObject` as OP's other answer, to illustrate the second example in the edit:

```
import operator
from contextlib import contextmanager


class MyObject:
    output_type = None

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    @classmethod
    def _convert(cls, value):
        if cls.output_type is None:
            return value
        return cls.output_type(value)

    @classmethod
    def _apply(cls, fn, a, b):
        return cls(fn(cls._convert(a), cls._convert(b)))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.value!r})"

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self._apply(operator.add, self.value, other.value)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self._apply(operator.sub, self.value, other.value)

    @classmethod
    @contextmanager
    def set_type(cls, output_type):
        old_behavior = cls.output_type
        try:
            cls.output_type = output_type
            yield
        finally:
            cls.output_type = old_behavior


print(MyObject(1) + MyObject(2.5))

with MyObject.set_type(int):
    print(MyObject(1) + MyObject(2.5))

with MyObject.set_type(str):
    print(MyObject(1) + MyObject(2.5))
```

outputs (annotated by me)

```
MyObject(3.5)  # no conversions
MyObject(3)  # everything converted to int
MyObject('12.5')  # everything converted to str
```

Comment: if we replaced the 5 and the 2 with a custom object, can i modify the result object to converted based on the giving type in the context manager?

Comment: Well yes, your context manager could modify the behavior of a custom object.

Comment: then this is my question, how i can modify the bahavior of a custom object??

Comment: I mean, by e.g. setting a global variable, setting a field on the object's class, ...?

Comment: no, of course this is not possible!, the only place when the type is set in in the "with statement"

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't follow that last comment. Anyway, please see my edit.

Comment: well, not what i am looking for, i don't want to change the operands, but only the result, and also without changing anything in my code about the with statement use

Comment: Then it's not possible.

Comment: check my answer to my question, and sorry if the question was not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

well i solve it finally,
the solution is to change the **add** **sub** methods of the operand,
so if the context class has a type not None, will converted it to the giving type. otherwise it will remain the same.

```
class MyObject:

    def __init__(self, value, ):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        new_obj = MyObject(self.value + other.value)
        if MyContextManager.output_type is not None:
            new_obj.conversion(my_context_manager.output_type)
        return new_obj

    def __sub__(self, other):
        new_obj = MyObject(self.value + other.value)
        if MyContextManager.output_type is not None:
            new_obj.conversion(my_context_manager.output_type)
        return new_obj

    def conversion(self, new_type):
        pass


class MyContextManager:
    output_type = None

    def __init__(self, output_type):
        self.output_type = output_type

    def __enter__(self):
        self.change_output(self.output_type)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.change_output(None)

    @classmethod
    def change_output(cls, output_type):
        cls.output_type = output_type
```

Comment: This is doing what I said with "set a field on an object's class". Also, as you've written it, it's buggy if you try to nest context managers.

Comment: but change the result not the operands, you alreay said it's not possible to change the type of the result only, about if it bugy if i used a nest context, well i had specific required, and this is really solved my problem, might be it's bugy in nest, i dont know, but if you can provider a better solution that will work, and not bugy in nest, it will be great

Comment: I did already provide it - the second example in my edited answer does what this does (just think of `MySpecialClass.behavior` being `MyContextManager.output_type`.

Comment: where is the with statement, i have a fixed with statement block, i write down in my question, i am just allowed to change the context class or the operands class, all of your solution are based on changing how the with block itself, witch is too far from my question.

Comment: Your original question doesn't mention a `MyObject` at all, you know?

Comment: Anyway, please see my other edit.

Comment: yes this is correct now